# SSRS 2016 report manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have installed SSRS 2016 developer locally on my machine.
I can't get the report manager page to load and in the log files I get this error:

Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 1355

I have search and seem to get back to this article each time:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/842423

But how would I do this or apply these on my local machine?
I have tried changing the service user to Network Service and Local Service/System, and also my domain login I use which has local admin rights but always get this same error.

Can anyone suggest anything else I can try?

Comment: What edition of windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in SQL 2016 SP1 update

Comment: What is your source? Do you have a link, for example?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP1 fixed this issue for me. I had the same issue on a stock RTM install (v13.0.1601.5); the initial portal would not come up and showed the error in the question. I installed SP1 (v13.0.4001.0) and am able to pull up the portal now. The closest links I could find referring to this behavior were [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3171505/fix-the-service-is-not-available-error-when-you-use-ssrs-2016-portal-a) or [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3171040/-http-503-service-unavailable-error-when-you-open-the-ssrs-web-portal).

Answer (score 0):

this appears very similar to a known issue with SQL 2016. A patch is due soon with Cumulative Update #1. If you are on a domain joined machine, and the server does not have access to the domain controller (e.g. you aren't VPN'd, don't have wifi, etc...) this AuthZ call will fail.